# Debian 9.1: Can't disable IPv6 autoconfig

Tags: debian, systemd

I've updated a machine to Debian 9.1 and everything seems to be fine, however I can't disable IPv6 autoconfig.

**Background**: I only want to use some specific IPv6 addresses on the machine that I'm defining in `/etc/systemd/network/10-static-eth0.network`:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Address=2a04:52c0:xxx:xxx::xxx/48
Address=2a04:52c0:xxx:xxx::xxx/48
Address=2a04:52c0:xxx:xxx::xx/48
Gateway=2a04:52c0:xxx::1

Address=5.2.xxx.xxx/25
Address=5.2.xxx.xxx/25
Address=5.2.xxx.xxx/25
Gateway=5.2.xxx.xxx
```

To disable IPv6 autoconfig I added the following at the end of `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf=0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf=0

net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra=0

net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_dad=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_dad=0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_dad=0
```

After rebooting there's no dynamic / autoconfig IPv6 address but after a while it appears on `ip addr show`:

```
inet6 2a04:52c0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx:xxxx:1e3d/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute dynamic 
   valid_lft 2590732sec preferred_lft 603532sec
```

How can I avoid this autoconfig IPv6 address and make sure only the static addresses get to work?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure your `net.ipv6.conf.*` settings are actually being applied?  Do you see them set to `0` if you inspect `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/*?

Comment: BTW, since you are using a systemd network unit, have you tried using the `IPv6AcceptRA=` option in your network unit?  https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html

Comment: @Zoredache I added that into my config lets see it if fixes the issue. Thank you all.

Comment: @Zoredache still getting a dynamic addr :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these addresses marked as `mngtmpaddr` and `noprefixroute` come from the [IPv6 Privacy Extensions standard (RFC 4941)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4941) and are created by the kernel itself.

You should be able to turn that feature off adding

```
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr=0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.use_tempaddr=0
```

to your `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Hope it helps!

Comment: And... I still got the `mngtmpaddr` `noprefixroute` address after a few hours :(

Comment: Weird.... My test box (a Xen VM with up to date debian 9, did not get a `mgmtmpaddr` after setting these sysctl entries). I wonder what could be the difference. Do the `0` values persist after the address appears? May be after a up/down cycle or other configuration done by automatically these get reset to `1` or `2`. Taking [this reference](https://blog.linitx.com/control-privacy-addressing-ipv6-linux/), there seems to be a timer, albeit for address lifespan.

Comment: If I cat cat `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/use_tempaddr` I get `0` and the address is there so yes, they persist. Same for `default` and `all`.

Comment: They also persist (stay as `0`) for `autoconf`, `accept_ra` and `accept_dad`.

Comment: I was wondering, is there a remote possibility that there is some "left over" from the old non-systemd networking causing this? What do you suggest? I've upgraded this system from older versions multiple times and I remember changing the network to systemd but not what I did exactly.

Comment: For whats worth, the `/etc/network` folder is still on my system. No `interfaces` file however, is it safe to delete that folder?